# Parse json to Case Class

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I've got the following JSON that I need to map 2 values to a case class
These values are **job_id** and **state**

The JSON is the following

```
{
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "browser": "chrome",
      "state": "pending",
      "url": "http://localhost/mirror/52ea1b22e4b0e133507b209b",
      "browser_version": "26.0",
      "os_version": "7",
      "id": "92342eed1fd14c354d9365cbbd3e35ea1fc45df2",
      "os": "Windows"
    }
  ],
  "wait_time": 5,
  "callback_url": "http://localhost/screenshot/accept/52ea1b22e4b0e133507b209b",
  "quality": "compressed",
  "job_id": "ce991c0c3d140b5a78859b28cf391fd99c63ff98",
  "win_res": "1024x768",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "mac_res": "1024x768"
}
```

With the case class being

```
case class JobInfo(job_id: String)

object JobInfo {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[JobInfo]
}
```

This works fine but i want to add the screenshot 'state' into the case class without having to have the whole scrernshot as I am only persisting job_id and state so something like the following

```
case class JobInfo(job_id: String, state: String)

object JobInfo {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[JobInfo]
}
```

I'm reading the response like this below but screenshot is an array so wanted to know how I could extract the JSON key 'state' from it and map it to the case class

```
    .map {
                response => {
    val jobInfo = Json.parse(response.body).as[JobInfo]    
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a custom Reads[JobInfo] object to handle the parsing.  Assuming you intend to grab the first element from the screenshots array to find the state, you could do it as follows:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object JobInfo {
  implicit val jobReads: Reads[JobInfo] = (
    (__ \ "job_id").read[String] and
    ((__ \ "screenshots")(0) \ "state").read[String]
  )(JobInfo.apply _)
}
```

Your original call to parse the json will now work; however, you should be using the validate method to properly handle the case where your JSON is not formatted as expected, i.e.:

```
Json.parse(response).validate[JobInfo].fold(
  jobInfo => {
    //do something with your jobInfo
    println(jobInfo)  
  },
  errors => {
    //handle JSON parsing errors
    println(errors)
  }
)
```

This way you handle parsing errors more gracefully.  The Play documentation describes this more in detail [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonCombinators)